# Font \grotesq (URW Grotesq 2031 Bold) not automatically installed when using tinytex/lualatex in R Markdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

How can I install the font "URW Grotesq 2031 Bold" with `tinytex`/`lualatex`? The font is included in miktex (see here: https://ctan.org/pkg/urw-grotesq
) but is not automatically downloaded when I knit my document. I want to use \rmdefault throughout my document, but the title should be written in URW grotesq.

Here is the `MWE`:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    latex_engine: lualatex
classoption: a4paper
geometry: left=2cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm
fontsize: 11pt
lang: de
header-includes:
-   \usepackage{textpos}
-   \usepackage{fontspec}
-   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
---

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

Some Text here in rmdefault...

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

\begin{textblock}{165}[0,1](30,140)
    \begin{minipage}[b]{120mm}
      \flushleft
        {\fontfamily{ugq}
        \bfseries
        \fontsize{32pt}{32}
        \selectfont
        SOME TITLE HERE \bigskip \\
        2022}           
    \end{minipage}
\end{textblock}

\newpage

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

Some Text here in rmdefault...
```

My output looks like this:

[image]

But the title font should look like this:
https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/urwgrotesk/

Example:
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI: your code works fine with a complete texlive installation instead of tinytex. It takes a bit to install a complete texlive distribution, but you only have to do it once and you'll never again have to deal with missing things.

Comment: Yes, thats absolutely a possibility, Sam, thanks! I hoped to avoid this because of the amount of packages included in TexLive  by now (>4000), but as you mentioned it's probably easier than searching for solutions like this... So I downloaded TexLive, 2h installing but it's working ;-)

Comment: Great to hear it is working!